# Regexp grouping and replaceAll with .* in Java duplicates the replacement

Tags: java, regex

I got a problem using Rexexp in Java. The example code writes out `ABC_012_suffix_suffix`, I was expecting it to output `ABC_012_suffix`

```
    Pattern rexexp  = Pattern.compile("(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = rexexp.matcher("ABC_012");
    String  result  = matcher.replaceAll("$1_suffix");

    System.out.println(result);
```

I understand that replaceAll replaces all matched groups, the questions is why is this regexp group `(.*)` matching twice on my string `ABC_012` in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably `.*` gives you "full match" and then reduces match to the "empty match" (but still a match). Try `(.+)` or `(^.*$)` instead. Both work as expected.

At regexinfo star is defined as follows:

> *(star) - Repeats the previous item zero or more times. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is not matched at all.

Answer (score 6):

```
Pattern regexp  = Pattern.compile(".*");
Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher("ABC_012");
matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$0_suffix"));
```

Same happens here, the output is:

```
ABC_012
ABC_012_suffix_suffix
```

The reason is hidden in the `replaceAll` method: it tries to `find` all subsequences that match the pattern:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.printf("Start: %s, End: %s%n", matcher.start(), matcher.end());
}
```

This will result in:

```
Start: 0, End: 7
Start: 7, End: 7
```

So, to our first surprise, the matcher *finds* two subsequences, `"ABC_012"` and another `""`. And it appends `"_suffix"` to both of them:

```
"ABC_012" + "_suffix" + "" + "_suffix"
```

Comment: A very good analysis. It is correct according to Regexp, since .* also matches "". However this is very confusing :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add "_suffix" to your input why don't you just do:

```
String result = "ABC_012" + "_suffix";
```

?

Comment: (I guess, that was not the question - the puzzling question was, why we have an extra _suffix added to the result)

Comment: @Andreas_D: true, but it gives the right result without complicating things with unnecessary regexes. Just trying to keep it simple :)