# JAVA regex pattern matcher replacechall duplicates input

Tags: java, regex

I am using a very simple example here:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)");
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher("10110");
    String returnString = matcher.replaceAll("DATUM $1");
```

gives returnString="DATUM 10110DATUM" instead of "DATUM 10110".

What is wrong here?

Edit: Although using (.+) solves the issue, it is still a very strange regex behavor. As (.*) already matches the whole input, java appends another - empty - group, that is NOT referenced as a second group (normally $2) in the replaceAll statement. But JAVA spits out this second group. Fortunately it does stop then, before adding more empty group matches.

Comment: It is a known issue that is repro in a lot of languages. The `.*` matches the string, and then the end of the string. So, you have two matches here.

Comment: use https://regex101.com. here you can easily find out the issue

Comment: Other online java regex testers are not that good :-((

Answer (score 2):

After digging more and more and found the STRANGE solution: [Regexp grouping and replaceAll with .* in Java duplicates the replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029042/regexp-grouping-and-replaceall-in-java+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl)

Instead of (.*) I now use (.+) to not get duplicate results on a null group :-((

the corrected sample is now:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)");
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher("10110");
    String returnString = matcher.replaceAll("DATUM $1");
```

and gives the correct "DATUM 10110"

Comment: Sure, it makes no sense using `.*` inside a `replaceAll`. When you need to remove, you usually want to remove *something*, not an empty string. It is only logical. Else, you need to use `^.*$`.

Comment: Note that this query still don't make much sense since it would be easier to concat the values yourself. Even a `String.format("DATUM %s", "10110");` would be enough for more complex concatenation. This group would be everything so why bother with a regex. Multiline, this would be the only valid reason I guess

Comment: This is part of a list of rules for search&replace by using regex. I.e. my code code can do a global s&r using \u001D=><FNC1> and another rule line saying (.+)=>$1\n. Complete code at https://github.com/hjgode/TotalFreedomDataEdit/blob/master/TotalFreedomRegex/src/main/java/hsm/demo/totalfreedom/DataEdit.java